# How to copy a column from one sheet to another in MS- Excel, with ID as reference

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 2 sheets in one excel file. I'd like to **copy only the `team` column** from sheet 2 to sheet 1. Both sheets have matching ID to relate to each other.

Sheet 1

| id | name | address | team |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Paul | 1st street |  |
| 456 | Kyle | 2nd Street |  |

Sheet 2

| id | name | team |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Paul | CL |
| 456 | Kyle | BSM |

And then sheet 1 will now look like this:

| id | name | address | team |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Paul | 1st street | CL |
| 456 | Kyle | 2nd Street | BSM |

I don't know where to start. I know though that this can be done in excel, and you can do programming on it. I don't want to manually input it since it's more than a hundred records.

Comment: Found this tutorial in youtube. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NaBakFrIZkA&ab_channel=Tuts%2BComputerSkills

Answer (score 2):

Okay so I am assuming all the headers are in first row. This can easily be done through Vlookup

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!A:C,3,FALSE)
```

Put this formula in column team in Sheet1. It will work.

Let me know if you need any further clarification.